# How to reset/clear order-by between two consecutive queries in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I am trying to call 2 consecutive queries in CodeIgniter, the first of which has an order-by clause. The trouble is, CodeIgniter is trying to use the order-by clause for the second query as well and throwing an error.

The code looks something like this:

```
 ...
 $sql = $this->db->get_where('expenses',array('category_id' => $category_id));
 $this->db->order_by("date", "asc");
 $data = $sql->result_array();

 foreach($data as $expense_rec)
 {
     $expense_id = $data['expense_id'];
     $sql2 = $this->db->get_where('expense_details',array('expense_id' => $expense_id));
     $detail_rec = $sql2->result_array();
 }
 ...
```

For the second query, the script throws the following error:

```
Unknown column 'date' in 'order clause'

SELECT * FROM (`expense_details`) WHERE `expense_id` = '4' ORDER BY `date` asc
```

Is there a way I can reset the order-by before calling the second query?

I am using CodeIgniter 1.7

P.S. I know that I can join the two queries into one but I am curious to know if there is a way for the above code to work in CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Running the query is what resets it.

You are placing the `order_by()` after you run the query, so it is not affecting the inital query, but it starts building the next query.

instead of...

```
$sql = $this->db->get_where('expenses',array('category_id' => $category_id));
$this->db->order_by("date", "asc");
$data = $sql->result_array();
```

do this...

```
$this->db->order_by("date", "asc");
$sql = $this->db->get_where('expenses',array('category_id' => $category_id));
$data = $sql->result_array();
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that the call to get_where() was actually executing the query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$this->db->_reset_select()` to clear things out.

Comment: To note - while that does work, it's not recommended if you (plan to) update your CodeIgniter version, as it's a private function (hence the leading underscore) and might not be available in future versions.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue. In my case, I'm building a query based on user input. Halfway into building the query, there may be an issue which causes me to stop building the query and exit the model. However, if other models are called after this with other Active Record calls, the previously built queries are added to, which is definitely not my intention.

What I did to solve this problem is copy the DB object to a new variable, and use that for my query building. That variable only exists within that model anyway, so is destroyed before it can affect other models. So:

```
$new_db = $this->db;
$new_db->where('user_status', 1);
```

etc.